# Where can I watch "Boku no Pico"?

Tags: boku-no-pico

I heard from my friend that there is this anime called *Boku no Pico* and he said it was really nice. However, I can't find it anywhere online.

Is it legally streamed somewhere online?

Comment: One should not deserve to watch boku no pico

Comment: the anime is considered Hentai or perverted so I don't think you can get your answer here. And every one seems to advise against watching it for some reason.

Comment: I 99% believe your friend was trolling you. As the answerer and this community have stated, you have been warned though.

Comment: I 99% believe that this post is trolling us as the anime community. *Draws giant greatsword*

Comment: Boku no pico is one of the most popular unrecommended hentai cleverly termed as anime. It has a very sick plotlines so it is most used by trollers to  fool people

Comment: I was many a times fooled thinking that "boku no pico" as a cannon of "boku no hero academia", a very good anime.

Comment: Boku no pico can be termed under categories of "yaoi", "shotacon"," "mindbreak"," cross-dressing"... It is story about a gay pedophile who manipulates a kid boy in sex with him.Visual imagery could be like a old guy getting aroused seeing a boy in his swimsuit (protagonist).   Description of this hentai is available in Wikipedia which is cringeworthy enough.  It is an illegal show and can be prosecuted in any country.  Fans of this hentai are mentally depraved/debauched as a matter of fact stated in Wikia.       .

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your friendship... especially if he/she isn't trolling you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can purchase the Boku no Pico dvd bundles on Amazon or eBay. Due to search history at office I will be not providing urls for this.

You can also google streaming services for yaoi hentai that provide the episodes, or simply just google Boku no Pico. Once again due to search history at office I can not provide urls for this. There are plenty of legal streaming services that can be found on google for yaoi hentai. I also recommend looking up the definition of yaoi hentai incase you aren't aware about the meaning.

Incase you are an innocent one, please be advised to watch this while fully being aware that your friendship might be ruined after 5 minutes (if not less). I also do advice not watching this at public places or places with other human beings.

Incase you know what you are looking for... have a good one.

Comment: Strictly speaking Boku no Pico isn't Yaoi, which is a genre aimed at girls. Boku no Pico is part of the Trap genre and is intended for a male audience. Other anime part of that genre are Natsuyasumi and Shounen Maid Curo-kun.

The Trap genre is vastly different from Yaoi. (Also keep in mind that both Trap and Yaoi are the English words. In Japan Trap is called Otoko-no-ko and Yaoi is called BL as in Boys Love.)